# How can I make sure that the VLOOKUP formula fills the entire column?

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

```
Sheets("MoM").Select

Range("H2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(C[-7],'Table Array'!C[-7]:C[2],8,FALSE)"
Range("H2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("H2:H" & Range("G" & Rows.Count).End  (xlUp).Row), Type:=xlFillSeries
```

The formula stops half way and does not continue the entire duration of the column. Please Help!

Comment: Are you sure your fomula is correct? Shlouldnt this be =VLOOKUP(`R`C[-7],'Table Array'!C[-7]:C[2],8,FALSE)?

Comment: this code will autofill col H up to the last row in col G.  are you saying it isn't doing that, or were you expecting it to do something else?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you used the Macro Recorder to get this code. The code you provide is what happens when you select the sheet called "MoM", followed by the cell H2, followed by typing in the `=VLOOKUP()` function in Excel. From there, I think you tried to drag the VLOOKUP formula to the right and get the values. The reason your code does not work is because VLOOKUP is trying to get relative references on your Table Array. However, you want absolute references in order for your code to work. In fact, the only value that should change from cell to cell on the "MoM" sheet will be your column reference on the VLOOKUP function. One solution is to use the following loop to change your column index on the VLOOKUP function:

```
Sub mcrFillRow()
'   Declare your variables
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim name As String
    Dim myTable As Range
'   Set some variables to make VLookup code easier to read
    name = Range("G2")
    Set myTable = Worksheets("Table Array").Range("F1:K7")
'   Clear any previous values
    Sheets("MoM").Range("H2:L2").Clear
'   For loop to go through the columns of the Table Array
    For i = 2 To 6
      Select Case i
          Case 2 'VLookup the second column
             Sheets("MoM").Range("H2") = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(name, myTable, i, False)
          Case 3 'VLookup the third column
             Sheets("MoM").Range("I2") = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(name, myTable, i, False)
          Case 4 'VLookup the fourth column
             Sheets("MoM").Range("J2") = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(name, myTable, i, False)
          Case 5 'VLookup the fifth column
             Sheets("MoM").Range("K2") = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(name, myTable, i, False)
          Case 6 'VLookup the sixth column
             Sheets("MoM").Range("L2") = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(name, myTable, i, False)
        End Select
    Next i
End Sub
```

For the `Table Array` and `MoM` sheets, I used the following set up in Excel:

[image]